# Does PureScript support “format strings” like C / Java etc.?

Tags: purescript

I need to output a number with leading zeros and as six digits. In C or Java I would use `"%06d"` as a format string to do this. Does PureScript support format strings? Or how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any module that would support a printf-style functionality in PureScript. It would be very nice to have a type-safe way to format numbers.

In the meantime, I would write something likes this:

```
import Data.String (length, fromCharArray)
import Data.Array (replicate)

-- | Pad a string with the given character up to a maximum length.
padLeft :: Char -> Int -> String -> String
padLeft c len str = prefix <> str
  where prefix = fromCharArray (replicate (len - length str) c)

-- | Pad a number with leading zeros up to the given length.
padZeros :: Int -> Int -> String
padZeros len num | num >= 0  = padLeft '0' len (show num)
                 | otherwise = "-" <> padLeft '0' len (show (-num))
```

Which produces the following results:

```
> padZeros 6 8
"000008"

> padZeros 6 678
"000678"

> padZeros 6 345678
"345678"

> padZeros 6 12345678
"12345678"

> padZeros 6 (-678)
"-000678"
```

---

**Edit:** In the meantime, I've written a small module that can format numbers in this way:
https://github.com/sharkdp/purescript-format

For your particular example, you would need to do the following:

If you want to format *Int*egers:

```
> format (width 6 <> zeroFill) 123
"000123"
```

If you want to format *Number*s

```
> format (width 6 <> zeroFill <> precision 1) 12.345
"0012.3"
```

Comment: I've actually started working on a library to support this: https://github.com/sharkdp/purescript-format

Comment: Cool, I’ll have a closer look what you are doing there with Monoid and Semigroup. BTW, your solution above is more general than the one I have written myself yesterday  I’m still trying to get the hang of PureScript (strict, no (:) for Array de-structuring in recursion, data type `Tuple` instead of `(,)`, and a few more things).

Comment: I have released a first version of purescript-format. I've updated my answer accordingly. The Semigroup/Monoid instance for the Properties is only used to combine them in an easy way.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, by defining `append` and providing an ‘empty’ default. Sieht gut aus 